# Requirejs module to use without require

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I've already read this post:

[Write Requirejs modules that work without requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106613/write-requirejs-modules-that-work-without-requirejs)

and also checked out almond. but I cannot get it to work.

My build file looks like this:

```
{
    "baseUrl" : "../",
    "name" : "build/almond",
    "include" : ["uploader"],
    "out" : "../uploader.min.js",
    "wrap" : {
        'startFile' : 'start.frag',
        'endFile' : 'end.frag'
    }
}
```

and my start.frag

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function') {
    define(factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    root.Uploader = factory();
  }
}(this, function () {
```

and my end.frag

```
    return require('uploader');
}));
```

It works fine with requirejs.

```
require(['uploader'], function(Uploader) {
 var uploader = new Uploader();
});
```

but I want to be able to use it without requirejs so I can just use the script-tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploader.js"></script>
<script>
 var uploader = new Uploader();
</script>
```

how can I achieve this or do I have to rewrite my library?

I think jQuery does this already.

Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work when you just include it?

Comment: What is `return require('uploader');` supposed to do when there is no `require` defined?

Comment: Almond itself is supposed to bake in a minimum of requirejs so it can load the modules itself.

Comment: Maybe you can attach it to the window Object in your namespace if it is no nodejs or requirejs module?

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: http://gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js/ You can also combine all scripts into one without the dependency to Modulerr.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so the problem was I was trying to do new Uploader, when I had already loaded the require library.

So I couldn't use both approaches.

But it works fine when I don't have requirejs at all.

I just wanted to let you know in case someone else has this problem in the future.

Comment: The linked answer in your OP provided the solution. You use define incorrectly. It should have three arguments with the id in the first, empty array in second, and the function in the third.